# Intellisense loading forever

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Recently installed 16.5 and Intellisense never ends to load on a fairly simple project: [image]

I have to say I'm running a Ryzen 3990 and a SSD, so quite amazed this things still happen. How it can be fixed? Basically whenever I try to see the methods of a class or refactor something is broken because intellisense is still loading.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Any similar experience or how it can be fixed? Basically whenever I
> try to see the methods of a class or refactor something is broken
> because itellisense is still loading.

Based on your description, this is quite a strange behavior and in my side(`Visual Studio Community 16.5.0`), it works well and do not show `loading intellisense forever`.(If necessary, please provide more detailed info)

So I think there are some problems with your vs environment, please try these suggestions:

**Suggestion**

1. If your project is created by other previous vs version, please close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin`, `obj` folder, then restart your project.

   Besides, try to create a new empty project and test whether this still happens.
2. Delete any vs component caches under `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx\ComponentModelCache`
3. Try to use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start VS, then open your project or disable all third party extensions under `Manage Extensions` menu to test whether this behavior is caused by a particular extension. And some third-party extensions  probably interfere with the execution of the vs background tasks, causing congestion.
4. Try to [do a fix in visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) to check whether VS is broken.

Comment: Removing those folders did the trick, I think it was happening when you load a Xamarin projects with compile time errors from the last time you opened it, but working again. Thanks.

Comment: This following Github page helped me fix the issue
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87770#issuecomment-569555092

Comment: For me and those who are in sanctions, after removing bin, obj folders just use vpn proxy to fix or download all needed packages and sit relax to finish up the task.
if that doesn't fix the packages try to uninstall a package of your project, when the prompt message to uninstall is shown then click on cancel.
This worked for me

Comment: Deleting .vs, bin and obj folders did it for me. No need of additional steps.

Comment: Step 2 worked for me. After installing Python Development Toolkit for Visual Studio none of the intellisense was working. Is now! Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar experience, just running Visual Studio once with administrator rights seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with **Visual Studio Professional 2022**.

I just **downgraded to VS Pro 2019** and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

I have a xamarin solution that errors on nuget package restore (due to some mixed platform package issues). Visual Studio 2022 17.2.6 has the issue where it is in an infinite loop and keeps retrying it.

**To fix this issue:**

- Turn of Visual Studio automatic package restore in settings.
- Use command line package restore manually when you occasionally require
  it via

  `> dotnet restore YourSolution.sln`

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, the **Build > Clean Solution** and then re-building it again helped me

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience with a fresh checkout of a big repo, which has many NuGet package references. Visual Studio seemed stuck with loading Intellisense.

It turned out a big download on Steam was holding back the NuGet package restore, somehow allowing the Intellisense not to complete loading (or at least extremely slowly). After pausing the download on Steam the packages we're restored and the loading finished.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a VPN on. It worked when I turned it off so it may be just a network issue.