# Visual Studio 2022 keeps loading IntelliSense

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2022

Every time when Visual Studio 2022 is done with loading IntelliSense, it starts again and again, even when I don't use or after restart Visual Studio 2022 and no git merge or pull was made. Below I've added a screenshot.

[image]

Tried also to look inside settings but didn't find anything useful. What else could I do?

Comment: Does this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60809441) can help you?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the **exact** same issue. Stuck on Intellisense Loading 17/17.

I [followed the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60809441/823732) of deleting the .vs folder, then manually deleted all /bin and /obj folders.

Restarted Visual Studio 2022 and rebuilt all.

Success. Solution is building again.

While I haven't done tests to determine what step exactly fixed the issue, my solution & projects were indeed created using a previous version of Visual Studio, as the linked thread mentions.

Comment: No don't work. If it's done, the `.vs` folder stands back and keeps loading. Probably it's the type of project that gices the error.

Comment: What do you mean by "the .vs folder stands back"? Are you unable to delete it? You should be able to delete it. If you can't try closing all Visual Studio instances before that.

Why do you believe it's an issue with the project type?